# Issue with Visual Studio Code and debugging Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am currently running on Ubuntu 20.04 with the 1.45.1 version of Visual Studio Code. I am using the Microsoft Python extension.

- VS Code: 1.45.1
- Python Extension 2020.5.78807
- Code Runner 0.10.0
- Python: 3.8.2
- Pip: 20.2

I have set break points in code and activate debugging (F5).  However I am unable to debug the application (again using F5).  I can run using Code Runner (right click Run Code) and it successfully run but break points are never hit.

I have found no solution or workaround other than using another IDE.  I am used to running in VS Code and would prefer to not have to switch IDE/editor.  Any help would be appreciated.

I can debug in PyCharm or IDLE, just not VS Code.

Comment: are you able to import the model from python IDLE?

Comment: Since I am able to debug in IDLE I guess the answer is yes I can import the modules.